# At what point in the day do plants start to absorb light for photosynthesis?

Tags: botany, photosynthesis

My plants sit on a small table in my only window, facing Northwest. They are thriving. They are obviously getting enough indirect light to survive year round. Maybe they have adapted?  They have never really been in direct sunlight.

1. At what point in the day do they start absorbing this light?
2. Also, if the sun has risen behind my apartment building on a dull January morning and the sky is light are they reaping any benefits yet?

My plants are:

- an asparagus fern with a small grapefruit tree in a tall open terrarium
- an African violet
- an aloe vera plant
- 2 sprouting avocado seeds
- a small house palm.

I live in Alberta, Canada near the 49th parallel. This is a very sunny part of the province. Your ponderances will be welcome.

Comment: You may want to post also at https://gardening.stackexchange.com